# Is there a way to render markdown mermaid diagrams in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: markdown, jetbrains-ide, mermaid, jetbrains-rider

I would like to use JetBrains Rider to edit mermaid diagrams but there doesn't seem to be a plugin for it (at least I couldn't find one). Is there any way to enable rendering of mermaid diagrams in Rider?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's actually really simple. Open settings and navigate to `Language & Frameworks`. Then enable mermaid.

[image: enable mermaid in JetBrains Rider]